# Spring MVC Hibernate + SQLite not Creating database

Tags: hibernate, sqlite, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I 'am using Spring MVC, Hibernate and SQLite and when I run the server every thing work but the data base is not created and there is no exception. And when I start the `persistence.xml` from a java class it create the dataBase

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "/META-INF/persistence-config.xml");
        String[] names = context.getBeanDefinitionNames();

        System.out.println(context.getBeanDefinitionCount());
        for (String name : names) {
            System.out.println("name Bean == " + context.getBean(name).getClass());
        }

}
```

this is the `persistence.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Load database property file -->

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Tell Spring where to scan for components -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.binov" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.hibernate" />


    <!-- Create datasource bean -->

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:franchise.db" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Create Entity manager - JPA -->

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.binov.franchise.*" />

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>

       <!--  <property name="persistenceProvider">
            <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
        </property>  -->

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

   <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

this is the `SQLiteDialect`

```
package org.hibernate.dialect;

import java.sql.Types;
import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect;

import org.hibernate.dialect.function.AbstractAnsiTrimEmulationFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.NoArgSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.VarArgsSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

public class SQLiteDialect extends Dialect {
  public SQLiteDialect() {
    registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "boolean");
    registerColumnType(Types.TINYINT, "tinyint");
    registerColumnType(Types.SMALLINT, "smallint");
    registerColumnType(Types.INTEGER, "integer");
    registerColumnType(Types.BIGINT, "bigint");
    registerColumnType(Types.FLOAT, "float");
    registerColumnType(Types.REAL, "real");
    registerColumnType(Types.DOUBLE, "double");
    registerColumnType(Types.NUMERIC, "numeric($p, $s)");
    registerColumnType(Types.DECIMAL, "decimal");
    registerColumnType(Types.CHAR, "char");
    registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "varchar($l)");
    registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longvarchar");
    registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "date");
    registerColumnType(Types.TIME, "time");
    registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "datetime");
    registerColumnType(Types.BINARY, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.VARBINARY, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARBINARY, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.CLOB, "clob");
    registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "boolean");

    //registerFunction( "abs", new StandardSQLFunction("abs") );
    registerFunction( "concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "", "||", "") );
    //registerFunction( "length", new StandardSQLFunction("length", StandardBasicTypes.LONG) );
    //registerFunction( "lower", new StandardSQLFunction("lower") );
    registerFunction( "mod", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "?1 % ?2" ) );
    registerFunction( "quote", new StandardSQLFunction("quote", StandardBasicTypes.STRING) );
    registerFunction( "random", new NoArgSQLFunction("random", StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER) );
    registerFunction( "round", new StandardSQLFunction("round") );
    registerFunction( "substr", new StandardSQLFunction("substr", StandardBasicTypes.STRING) );
    registerFunction( "substring", new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "substr(?1, ?2, ?3)" ) );
    registerFunction( "trim", new AbstractAnsiTrimEmulationFunction() {
        protected SQLFunction resolveBothSpaceTrimFunction() {
          return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "trim(?1)");
        }

        protected SQLFunction resolveBothSpaceTrimFromFunction() {
          return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "trim(?2)");
        }

        protected SQLFunction resolveLeadingSpaceTrimFunction() {
          return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "ltrim(?1)");
        }

        protected SQLFunction resolveTrailingSpaceTrimFunction() {
          return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "rtrim(?1)");
        }

        protected SQLFunction resolveBothTrimFunction() {
          return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "trim(?1, ?2)");
        }

        protected SQLFunction resolveLeadingTrimFunction() {
          return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "ltrim(?1, ?2)");
        }

        protected SQLFunction resolveTrailingTrimFunction() {
          return new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "rtrim(?1, ?2)");
        }
    } );
    //registerFunction( "upper", new StandardSQLFunction("upper") );
  }

  public boolean supportsIdentityColumns() {
    return true;
  }

  /*
  public boolean supportsInsertSelectIdentity() {
    return true; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
  }
  */

  public boolean hasDataTypeInIdentityColumn() {
    return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
  }

  /*
  public String appendIdentitySelectToInsert(String insertString) {
    return new StringBuffer(insertString.length()+30). // As specify in NHibernate dialect
      append(insertString).
      append("; ").append(getIdentitySelectString()).
      toString();
  }
  */

  public String getIdentityColumnString() {
    // return "integer primary key autoincrement";
    return "integer";
  }

  public String getIdentitySelectString() {
    return "select last_insert_rowid()";
  }

  public boolean supportsLimit() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean bindLimitParametersInReverseOrder() {
    return true;
  }

  protected String getLimitString(String query, boolean hasOffset) {
    return new StringBuffer(query.length()+20).
      append(query).
      append(hasOffset ? " limit ? offset ?" : " limit ?").
      toString();
  }

  public boolean supportsTemporaryTables() {
    return true;
  }

  public String getCreateTemporaryTableString() {
    return "create temporary table if not exists";
  }

  public boolean dropTemporaryTableAfterUse() {
    return true; // TODO Validate
  }

  public boolean supportsCurrentTimestampSelection() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean isCurrentTimestampSelectStringCallable() {
    return false;
  }

  public String getCurrentTimestampSelectString() {
    return "select current_timestamp";
  }

  public boolean supportsUnionAll() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean hasAlterTable() {
    return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
  }

  public boolean dropConstraints() {
    return false;
  }

  /*
  public String getAddColumnString() {
    return "add column";
  }
  */

  public String getForUpdateString() {
    return "";
  }

  public boolean supportsOuterJoinForUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  public String getDropForeignKeyString() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No drop foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
  }

  public String getAddForeignKeyConstraintString(String constraintName,
      String[] foreignKey, String referencedTable, String[] primaryKey,
      boolean referencesPrimaryKey) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No add foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
  }

  public String getAddPrimaryKeyConstraintString(String constraintName) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No add primary key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
  }

  public boolean supportsIfExistsBeforeTableName() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean supportsCascadeDelete() {
    return true;
  }

  /* not case insensitive for unicode characters by default (ICU extension needed)
  public boolean supportsCaseInsensitiveLike() {
    return true;
  }
  */

  public boolean supportsTupleDistinctCounts() {
    return false;
  }

  public String getSelectGUIDString() {
    return "select hex(randomblob(16))";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put an absolute URL (with W / R permissions) in your JDBC URL property?

For example:

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:c:\\franchise.db" /> (in Windows)
```

Check if the database was created on the right path (C:/franchise.db).